# Advices on my Deck Builder's database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am working on a deck builder for an online card game (Kind of like Heartstone) and I am seeking advices about how I should handle my database.

To summarize it quickly : Each card can be *common / uncommon / rare / legendary / infinite*.

Should I create one table called **cards** in which I add a column *rarity (VARCHAR)* where I'll write *common / uncommon / rare / legendary / infinite* for each card like this ?

```
card -> id, name, class, type, rarity (VARCHAR), cost, attack, defense
```

Or should I create two tables, one called **cards** with *rarity (INT)* and another table called **rarity** where I list every rarity and use their *id* in my **cards** table like this ?

```
card -> id, name, class, type, rarity (INT), cost, attack, defense
rarity -> id, name
```

Also, would any of these option be better for multilingual purposes or is it basically the same ? (I never created a multilingual website on my own before, so I'm sorry if it's a dumb question)

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that a flat structure is faster, and your second option is not really doing anything, go with the first.

That said, you could try:

```
card -> id, name, class, type, cost, attack, defense
rarity -> id, name
Card_rarity --> card_id, rarity_id
```

Comment: So your solution would be faster than the second one I listed even though there's an additional tab ? 

Also, there are other factors (such as class, type of creatures, etc) so that would mean I'd have 2 more tables per factors ?

Comment: @Tokipudi No, the first, flat structure is faster. The normalised approach is better for data integrity. Take a look at [this](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization) for an indepth reason to go normalized

Comment: According to this article (and the related one at the top), even though flat is faster it's not "reliable" enough and shouldn't be used often. So I'll look more into the way you described, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can go halfway and setup the rarity as a CHAR(3) then use abreviations: COM UNC RAR LEG INF

Your second table should be a universal lookup tables for the other enumerable values (class,type)

```
LOOKUP_ID CHAR(8)     -- PK class,type,rarity
CODE CHAR(3)          -- PK key code 
LANG VARCHAR(10)      -- PK e.g. en-US
LABEL VARCHAR(255)    -- Short label for UI components
FULLTEXT VARCHAR(255) -- Full description for help etc...
```

Sample data

```
RARITY    COM     en  Common    Common card
RARITY    COM     fr  Commune   Carte commune
CLASS     COM     en  Combat    Combat has both defence and offence stats
CLASS     COM     fr  Combat    Les cartes combat possèdent des stats défence et offence
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying (sorry, it's been a while since I had sql at school ^^) 
I understand that it's basically the same way as I described but with abreviations instead of INT and that the `LANG` makes me able to choose which language I want. But I don't think I understand everything else from this second table. 

What's `LOOKUP_ID` and `CODE` exatcly ? 

Also, could I just use the normalized way @JohnHC described and handle the multilingual part later ?

Comment: Say you have class = COMbat and rarity=COMmon. You need to distinguish both of them in the "dictionary" table

Comment: Oh okay. So it'd be one table with every rarity / classes / types in every language I need.
It means that in my **cards** table I should create every card twice with a LANG column if I want them to be in french and english ?

Again, sorry if my questions are kinda dumb, I've never done this before.